# Sort same value fields in list descending

Tags: c#, list

How can I sort same value fields in generic lists with a descending order.

Example:

```
List<int> objList = new List<int>();

objList.Add(1);
-> objList.Add(0);
-> objList.Add(0);
objList.Add(2);
-> objList.Add(0);
```

It's my source somehow and I want to sort for example zero values in descending mode.

I use this code for sorting the numbers (actually the depths), and above example is not related to this but somehow it's same. In my generic list I have several depths which they might be same to each other and I want to order the same fields descending.

```
Objects.Sort(
   delegate(Classes.Object.GameObject Object1, Classes.Object.GameObject Object2)
   {
       return Object1.Depth.CompareTo(Object2.Depth);
   }
);
```

**Answer:** Might help someone in the future

```
    // Reverse same oredered
    CurrentSameOrderedFind = Objects[0].Depth;
    CurrentSameOrderedID = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Objects.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Objects[i].Depth != CurrentSameOrderedFind)
        {
            SameOrederedFound = true;
            Objects.Reverse(CurrentSameOrderedID, i - 1);
            CurrentSameOrderedFind = Objects[i].Depth;
            CurrentSameOrderedID = i;
        }
    }
    if (!SameOrederedFound)
    {
        Objects.Reverse();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. For example, "above example is not related to this but somehow it's same" - what does that mean? If you can explain the question more clearly, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: :) I don't know how much more should I expand it. It's simple, re-order the same valued fields in descending order. It's like you have `(Field[0] = 0, Field[1] = 1, Field[2] = 0)` And then The result should be `(Field[2], Field[0], Field[1]);` Easy!

Comment: No, not easy at all - what exactly do you mean by "the same valued fields"? If you could give a short but *complete* example showing your input and desired output, that would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your list sorted in descending order based on `GameObject.Depth`, and you've got an implementation that sorts your collection, but in ascending order rather than descending. Given that, here's the laziest answer I could come up with:

Code edited per my comment. Really, why couldn't you have said what you wanted in the question? I agree that it isn't complicated, but you won't get good help if you don't ask good questions.

```
   List<GameObject> oldList = new List<GameObject>(Objects); 
   Objects.Sort( 
       delegate(Classes.Object.GameObject Object1, Classes.Object.GameObject Object2) 
       { 
           int compareValue = -1 * Object1.Depth.CompareTo(Object2.Depth); 
           if(compareValue == 0)
               compareValue = oldList.IndexOf(Object2).CompareTo(oldList.IndexOf(Object1));
           return compareValue;
       } 
    );
```

Hardly optimal, but it's not meant to be.

Comment: @MahanGM - Then you'll need an additional property to compare against, at least for the `delegate` syntax you've been using already, and you haven't specified one. I'll edit my answer, using list index as that property (in descending order, so list[0] appears after list[1] if they both have the same depth), since I have a sneaking suspicion that's what you want, for whatever reason, based on your question's comments.

Comment: I did But there are some questions that they asked so few times and they have no clear point!. About updated code, It looks nice but is it just care for zero values? The same values can be any number.

Comment: @MahanGM - This code will sort your list (`Objects`) based first on `Depth` (higher values first) then on previous index value (again, highest first). So if Objects = { A, B, C, D } with respective depth values { 1, 0, 2, 0 }, the results of the sort would be { C, A, D, B }. If you instead want low depth first but still highest index first - that is, the result { D, B, A, C } - just remove `-1 *`.

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about for 1 hour! Thanks. I'll put your name in my credit :)

Answer (score 4):

To sort a `List<int>`, which your code above shows, in descending order, there's a very simple Linq solution: `objList = objList.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();`

From reading the rest of your question, do you want to sort a list of objects with a depth property?  If so, this should work for you:

```
var myList = new List<someTypeWithDepth>();
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(o => o.depth).ToList();
```

If in whatever situation you're using these Lists you can get away with typing them as `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` then you could remove those ugly `ToList()` calls

Comment: The OrderByDescending calls (as with all LINQ) are not going to order the List<T>, they will return the ordered data as IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>

Comment: Nice shot! I'll try it. But what did Aron Mclver say?

Comment: @MahanGM - Aaron was pointing out a slight bug in my code.  It should be fixed now.